# how to make rounded inner rectangle for button using css?

Tags: html, css

is there a way in making the inner rectangle rounded using 4px border-radius?
rounded corners start when a value greater than 4px is set but I am under constraint to have it 4px.

Is this possible or I should demand the constraint be amended?

[image]

https://codepen.io/jicking/pen/WNRvjpZ

```css
div {
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn {
  width: 82px;
  height: 32px;
  color: #0d4773;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #0c6699;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="btn">test</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet

Comment: You could also use `border-image` along with `radial-gradient` (sry, too lazy to implement it).

Answer (score 0):

Possibly no way to round up the inner rectangle because it's inside border. The work-around is to add a span that wraps around the button:

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #333333;
}

.btn {
  width: 82px;
  height: 32px;
  color: #0d4773;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #0c6699;
  /*background-clip: padding-box;*/
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  /*set to 5px + for inner rect rounded*/
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.btn-outer {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 4px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #0c6699;
}
```

```html
<span class="btn-outer">
  <button class="btn">test</button>
</span>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Why not use `button::before`?

Comment: yeah, that's another work-around, the rectangle inside is inside border

Comment: Then wouldn't you agree that's preferrable because it doesn't require touching the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Using pseudoelement `:before`:

```css
body {background-color:#000; margin:40px;}
.btn {
  background-color:#fff;
  width: 82px;
  height: 32px;
  color: #0d4773;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  border-radius:4px;
  position:relative;
}
.btn:before {
  content:'';
  width:94px;
  height:44px;
  border-radius:8px;
  display:block;
  border: 4px solid #0c6699;
  top:-10px;
  left:-10px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">
  test
</button>
```

Comment: In CSS 2.1 it was `:before`. In current CSS 3 it has been `::before` for almost 10 years now. OP obviously uses CSS 3 (otherwise they wouldn't have things like `background-clip`, `border-radius`, `box-shadow`)